# Не получается считать локальный файл SWIFT

Tags: swift, swift4

При попытке считать содержимое файла, вызывается обработка ошибки.

```
do {
    let dictionary = try String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/mihail/test.txt", encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(dictionary)
} catch {
    print("ooops")
}
```

Файл точно находится по данному адрессу. Не могли бы подсказать, где находится ошибка, либо предложить свой вариант решения данной задачи? Использую SWIFT 4.2

Comment: В блоке catch можно получить более подробную ошибку. Не могли бы вы включить ее в ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать новый проект и вставьте это во ViewController.swift вместо его содержимого. У меня на рабочем столе создается файл и в консоли все нормально выводится. Или там появятся описания ошибок, если файлы создаваться или читаться не будут. Обязательно проверьте путь указанный в константе currentDir, а то вдруг имя пользователя неверное.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let fileName = "Myfile.txt"
  let fileContent = "Saving to file on Desktop checking"

  // ПРОВЕРЬТЕ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ЮЗЕРНЭЙМ !!!
  let currentDir = "/Users/mihail/Desktop"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    saveStringToFile(string: fileContent, fileName: fileName)
    let loadResult = loadFileToString(fileName: fileName)
    if let result = loadResult {
      print("Text from file: ", result)
    } else {
      print("Text not loaded")
    }
  }

  // Выгрузка данных из файла в строковую переменную
  func loadFileToString(fileName: String) -> String? {
    var resultString: String?
    let filePath = currentDir + "/" + fileName

    do {
      resultString = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
      print("File \(fileName) with \(resultString!.count) symbols is loaded")
    }
    catch {
      print("Loading from file \(fileName) error. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return resultString
  }

  // Сохранение данных из строковой переменной в файл
  func saveStringToFile(string: String, fileName: String) {
    let filePath = currentDir + "/" + fileName

    do {
      try string.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
      print("File " + fileName + " created and string loaded successfully.")
    }
    catch {
      print("Saving to file \(fileName) error. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

Вывод консоли, если без ошибок:

File Myfile.txt created and string loaded successfully.

File Myfile.txt with 34 symbols is loaded

Text from file:  Saving to file on Desktop checking

Answer (score 0):

Из приложения Вы можете "видеть" только файлы в своей песочнице (каталог, где хранятся все файлы установленного приложения). Используйте FileManager для получения содержимого файла.

Update

Как уже предложено в комментарии к вопросу, попробуйте вывести ошибку на консоль:

```
} catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Странно. Я загружал файлы с рабочего стола. По примерно такому пути "/Users/myusername/Desktop/file.txt". И мой код выглядит практически так же как и у спрашивающего. И нормально сохранял туда же.

Comment: Ну вообще это краеугольный камень безопасности мобильных приложений Apple, что они не имеют доступа к файлам из другой области видимости, кроме своей песочницы. Посмотрите, где хранятся на диске файлы приложений, которые установлены на симуляторе. Вы точно загружали файлы с диска из приложения, установленного на симуляторе?

Comment: Да конечно. Я понимаю о какой песочнице Вы имеете ввиду. Там ещё очень длинный путь, я получал его через (var currentDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]). Просто я писал парсер для html и для удобства (чтобы не выискивать эти пути и папки) загружал исходные файлы с рабочего стола макбука. Туда же сохранял и результирующий файл. Может на устройстве ограничения действуют в полной мере, а с симулятором менее строго. Не знаю.

Comment: Нет, так это другое дело, полный путь к песочнице действительно будет начинаться с Users/username, например, /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B9BA10C6-F5F8-409F-968B-AC28F1BA6907/data/Containers/Data/Application/4764AFDE-F166-4778-98D2-3FD8EF9E14F3/. Но к папке Users/username/file доступа не будет, только к файлам в песочнице, поэтому Вы и вычисляли полный путь.

Comment: Вы не поняли меня :) Про вычисление пути я написал просто для того, чтобы показать, что я понимаю, о чем Вы говорите. А файлы я сохранял и читал используя рабочий стол макбука то есть по пути: "/Users/username/Desktop/file.txt" как и у топикстартера.

Comment: Да, действительно, я не прав, попробовал, файл читается. Видимо прав хватает на уровне пользователя системы, поэтому есть доступ. Исправлю ответ, спасибо )

Comment: Да ничего, нельзя все знать :) Я вообще новичок, просто сталкивался с этим.